# not able to open multiple files using fatfs file system and ff.c library

Tags: c

hi i am new to fatfs file system and i want to read and write data to my pen drive using fat file system libraries. i am able to read and write individual files but my project needs me to open two files at a time and write something into it.but doing it returns FR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES error. i don't know how to remove it. please help. the sequence that i am using to open and write into the files is as follows.

```
rc = f_open(&My_File_Object_x, "0:/Hello.TxT", FA_WRITE | FA_READ | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
if(rc) {  die(rc); }                                                                      
rc = f_open(&rightcount, "0:/Hell.TxT", FA_WRITE | FA_READ | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
if(rc) {  die(rc); }                                
rc = f_write(&My_File_Object_x, "Hello world!\r\n", 14, &bw);
if(rc) {  die(rc); } 
rc = f_write(&rightcount, "Hello world!\r\n", 14, &bw);
if(rc) {  die(rc); }                                
rc= f_sync(&My_File_Object_x);                             
if(rc) {  die(rc); }                               
rc= f_close(&My_File_Object_x);                             
if(rc) {  die(rc); }                           
rc= f_sync(&rightcount);                             
if(rc) {  die(rc); }                           
rc= f_close(&rightcount);                             
if(rc) {  die(rc); }
```

Comment: Can you post a compilable example (include the relevant variable declarations/initializations, `f_mount` call, etc). And let us know exactly which line the error is occurring on.

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration file "ffconf.h" where you can find a option named **_FS_LOCK**. According to manual from "FatFs":

> If value is >0:   Enable file lock feature. The value defines how many files/sub-directories can be opened simultaneously under file lock control.

and

> FR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES:
>       Number of open objects has been reached maximum value and no more object can be opened. (Related option: _FS_LOCK)

With your information provided I can only guess that your **_FS_LOCK** has value 1.